# Add different classes automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this jquery  code and work great.

```js
var styles = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifh"];
var index = 0;
$("body").find("h3").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass(styles[index++]);
  if (index >= styles.length) index = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>A</h3>
<h3>B</h3>
<h3>C</h3>
```

but i have about "100" h3 tags in my page, can i add automatic a different class to all of them? 
Thanks

Comment: That is what your code is already doing...? Also note you can use the `index` argument provided to the `each()` handler function instead of maintaining your own variable.

Comment: Can't CSS `h3:nth-child(0)` to `h3:nth-child(4)` do what you want?

Comment: my code right now its make ""first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifh"" and then start again with "first" i need different for 100 h3

Comment: What should those 100 different classes be?

Comment: from "one" to "hundred" or anything else.

Comment: @Vachos You still haven’t addressed _why_ you need all those class names and why you’re not simply using `h3:nth-child(` _n_ `)` or `section:nth-child(` _n_ `) h3` for any 1 ≤ _n_ ≤ 100, as [str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560761/add-different-classes-automatic#comment84117143_48560761) already pointed out.

Comment: Well that's a very odd requirement as classes are supposed to group elements. Unique classes is an anti-pattern. As @Xufox mentioned, could you explain why you believe you need to do this, as I'm certain there's a better way to achieve what you require.

Comment: Ok can i retype my question. I need different class added for 9 first h3 and different after that. Its that ok? Sorry for wrong question.

Comment: @Vachos Isn’t that what your code is almost doing already?

Comment: My code now add class "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifh" and after that start from begin "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifh". @Xufox

Answer (score 0):

use `.each()` by passing a function with the first parameter as the index. It will do the magic for you.

```
$("body").find("h3").each(function(i) {

  $(this).addClass('random_class_' + i);

});
```

Comment: And what happens when he has 100 h3 and only 5 classes in the array?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks. Fixed my answer.